# Missing Hebrew vowels in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, hebrew

Since I had some [annoying warnings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/512720/135685) with XeLaTeX and Polyglossia, I tried my luck with LuaLaTeX. Unfortunately Polyglossia simply returns a complaint in a warning:

```
Package polyglossia Warning: Hebrew is not supported with LuaTeX.
```

(Any ideas in comment are welcome to fix this!)

So I tried the `bidi` feature of `babel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=en-GB,main]{british}
\babelprovide[import=he]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Times New Roman}
\babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{Courier New}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Script=Hebrew,Language=Default,Ligatures=TeX,Contextuals=Alternate]{SBL Hebrew}

\begin{document}
Random text.

\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

However, this way some diacritics are missing in Hebrew (in this case the *dagesh* in the *shin):*

[image: Missing dagesh]

How could I fix this strange mistake? I'm using MikTeX 2.9.7219 portable on Windows 7 64 bit, everything is updated as of 2 days ago.

<sub>The reason for using the `Language=Default` option:
[Language 'Hebrew' not available for font 'DejaVu Sans' with script 'Hebrew'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472639/135685)</sub>

<sub>The reason for defining serif and mono fonts even when not using it:
[Why babel produce warnings about \rmfamily and \ttfamily with \babelfont](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511079/135685)</sub>

Comment: you probably will need a harfbuzz based engine.  So either xelatex, or the experimental luahbtex along with a development version of luaotfload.

Comment: @Ulrike I'd need Lua for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13792/135685

Comment: @Kazibácsi Maybe [luatex-harfbuzz](https://github.com/tatzetwerk/luatex-harfbuzz) works for you

Comment: `luahbtex` has lua, it is luatex + harfbuzz library. In miktex there is also a harftex variant which is similar. But I don't know if the newest luaotfload code will still work with it - it is target against luahbtex. For a texlive system you can get luahbtex from w32tex.org.

Comment: @Ulrike Unfortunately I'm totally unfamiliar with Harfbuzz and its implementation. I was trying to google something, but couldn't find much on Windows.