# The exam class with babel

Tags: babel, exam, hebrew

I am using `babel` and LaTeX extensively, but have encountered an error I do not understand and would be grateful to get your assistance on.

I have prepared 2 MWE that demonstrate that merely changing this:

```latex
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

to that:

```latex
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
```

produces an error in the `exam` class, but not in the `article` class.

Surprisingly:

1. the error is produced even without using Hebrew.
2. The error cannot be replicated with other languages (such as French, or even Arabic which is also RTL language).

MWE 1 - article class produces output:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item abc
\begin{itemize}
\item bcd
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

MWE 1 produces the following output:
[image]

MWE 2 - exam class won't produce output:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\question What is the result of 1+1?
\begin{choices}
\choice 1
\CorrectChoice 2
\choice 3
\choice 4
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

If you remove the word `hebrew` from `babel` package options, the `exam` class will produce the following.

[image]

The error in the console is:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild
```

Comment: exam uses `\ifnum \thepageof@pagepoints > 0` which doesn't work if `\thepageof@pagepoints` doesn't expand to a number (which it doesn't with hebrew as it changes the meaning of \@arabic).

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: I would use xelatex or lualatex-dev and code like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472639/language-hebrew-not-available-for-font-dejavu-sans-with-script-hebrew.